# A logo that shrinks and enlarges on the sidemenu - Ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic and I've been struggling to add a logo to the sidebar menu which will shrink / expand when you switch from portrait to landscape. See example below,

[image]

Why I want to shrink the logo is so that all the items can be shown together and the user doesn't have to scroll. This would apply to smaller screens as well (If all the items can't be shown in one screen the logo should reduce it's size to make room.)

This is my template,

```
<ion-side-menu side="left">

  <ion-header-bar class="logo">
  < img src="/images/logo.png" />
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="x.1" class="item-icon-left"> 1 </ion-item>
      <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="x.2" class="item-icon-left"> 2 </ion-item>
      <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="x.3" class="item-icon-left"> 3 </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-side-menu>
```

and the CSS

```
.logo img {
        max-height:     56px;
        max-width:      120px;
        margin:     0 auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
        display:    block;

}
```

Comment: you can get the device width and use ng-class accordingly to adjust its size...